# PHP fsocketopen port 25 verses mail()

Tags: php, email

I am looking at two classes used for sending emails from PHP scripts.  One uses `fsocketopen` to port 25 and the other uses PHP `mail()` for sending.  I understand with `fsocketopen` I can do better error handling based on server responses, other than that, what are the pros / cons for each? 
Or if anyone could point me to documentation - I've been unable to find information on the pros and cons - that would be equally helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`mail` does everything for you, `fsocketopen` requires you write the all the headers for the email. If you're fine with doing it manually, `fsocketopen` is a decent approach. They both have their trade offs.. `mail` is easy but slightly more restrictive, `fsocketopen` is harder to use, but allows you to do whatever you want.